# UITableView load data

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, tableview

I'm trying to populate a tableview in my app but I don't know how to make a function to start populating it. I'd like to do this because I receive data from an http request but the array that will contain it is empty when tableview datasource needs to be updated.
Is it possible? I'm using Swift.

This is my code:

```
class ContractsViewController: UIViewController, UISearchBarDelegate, UITableViewDelegate, UITableViewDataSource {

var companyTxt: String = ""
var descriptionTxt: String = ""
var idTxt: String = ""
var dateCreatedTxt: String = ""
var dateExpirationTxt: String = ""
var savedData = Dictionary<Int, JSON>()
var json: JSON = []


@IBOutlet weak var searchContracts: UISearchBar!
@IBOutlet weak var tableView: UITableView!
@IBOutlet weak var myIndicator: UIActivityIndicatorView!


override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    preUpload()

}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


func preUpload() {

    let headers = [
        "X-Limit": "5",
        "X-Sort": "{\"expirationDate\":-1}"
    ]


    myIndicator.color = (UIColor.redColor())
    myIndicator.startAnimating()


    Async.background {

        Alamofire.request(.GET, "https://mydata", headers: headers)
            .responseJSON { response in
                switch response.result {
                case .Success (let data):

                    self.json = JSON(data)

                    let replaced = FindAndReplace().findAndReplace(self.json)

                    for (pos, object): (String, JSON) in replaced {
                        print("")
                        print("pos -> " + pos)
                        self.savedData[Int(pos)!] = object
                    }

                case .Failure(let error):
                    print(error)
                }
        }

        }.main {

            self.myIndicator.stopAnimating()

    }


}


override func touchesBegan(touches: Set<UITouch>, withEvent event: UIEvent?) {
    self.searchContracts.resignFirstResponder()
}


// MARK: TableView


func tableView(tableView: UITableView, numberOfRowsInSection section: Int) -> Int
{
    //return name.count
    print("Json count -> " + String(json.count))
    return json.count
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, cellForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCell
{
    let cell: ServiceContractsCell? =  tableView.dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier("cellServiceContracts", forIndexPath: indexPath) as? ServiceContractsCell

    let value = self.savedData[(indexPath.row)]
    let valueMapped = Mapper<ServiceContract>().map(String(value))

    cell?.descriptionText.text = valueMapped?.description



    return cell!
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canEditRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
{
    return false
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, commitEditingStyle editingStyle: UITableViewCellEditingStyle, forRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    self.tableView?.deleteRowsAtIndexPaths([indexPath], withRowAnimation: UITableViewRowAnimation.Top)

}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> UITableViewCellEditingStyle
{
    return (UITableViewCellEditingStyle.Delete)
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, canMoveRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath) -> Bool
{
    return true
}

func tableView(tableView: UITableView, didSelectRowAtIndexPath indexPath: NSIndexPath)
{
    print("row = %d",indexPath.row)

}



}
```

Thanks in advance.

**Edit**
I can't use reloadData() and self.tableView.delegate/datasource in viewDidLoad()

Comment: You need to call `tableView.reloadData()` once you got and parser your JSON data.

Comment: As Larme stated up here, you got to call reloadData() in order to make the table view display the new values.

Comment: Should I use reloadData() in the .main? Because I have nil exception if I try this

Answer (score 0):

Under your Alamo call, update the main closure to this:

```
}.main {
self.myIndicator.stopAnimating()
self.tableView.reloadData()
}
```

Comment: I can't find reloadTable(), only reloadData() but I have nil exception if I try to use that method

Answer (score 0):

In the comments, you mentioned that you have a nil exception if you try to reload the data. Make sure your tableView is connected to your IBOutlet. Then make sure you have this in your viewDidLoad.

```
tableView.delegate = self
tableView.dataSource = self
```

After that, you should be able to call

```
tableView.reloadData()
```

From the main thread

Comment: I match and delegate in the storyboard and now I added the two lines in the viewDidLoad(), I try to call tableView.reloadData in the .main but I still have nil exception, thanks anyway

Answer (score 0):

All the UI update should be in the main thread only, Can you please call the `tableView.reloadData()` like below

```
dispatch_async(dispatch_get_main_queue()) { () -> Void in
        self.tableView.reloadData()
   }
```